# In TCL, what are ".list" and ".desc" syntax used for? Where can I learn more about them?

Tags: tcl, procedure

I'm trying to understand some code written in TCL and convert it to Python. I skimmed through online docs for the TCL/TK language, and attempted some web searches, but I can't seem to find any documentation or description of what these syntax elements are: ".list" and ".desc"

Can anyone describe what this is called in TCL so that I can find references material about what it does?

Here's a small sample of the code. These appear to usually be found inside procedures. It seems like they setup or configure something.

```
proc makelist {args number } {
    .list delete 0 end
    .desc configure -state normal
    .desc delete 0 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They appear to be widgets. In Tk, widget path names must begin with `.`.

For example in your code, `.list` could be the path name of an [entry](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/entry.htm#M44) widget (which supports the `delete` subcommand and which here would mean to delete everything that's in that entry's box). `.desc` could be the pathname of another entry widget.

Comment: Yes! Thanks. That's it. I see where some of this stuff is generated now much farther down inside a TK GUI loop section of code. The original programmer named a listbox widget literally as ".list," and I didn't understand how that syntax worked. That was confusing.

I thought it was maybe some property or method of the data being created locally inside this procedure. Of course I didn't find a reference in the TCL docs I was looking up, it belongs to TK.